# After pg-related pop-up calls and processing, the web application JSESSION is broken

Tags: web, redirect, filter, popup, jsessionid

When the web application calls a pop-up related to pg for self-authentication and then redirects the pop-up in the web application, JSESSION has a null value, which is causing an error to create a new JSESSION and re-login. This error occurs intermittently once every 5 times, making it difficult to find the cause and solution.

Even after you set up Chrome's Allow Third-Party Cookies, the symptoms are the same, which seems unrelated to SameSiteNone settings.

I want to control it through Spring filter, but when I log HttpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId() in Spring filter, it is already set to null.

When I call the screen of my web application in an external pop-up related to pg, my web application takes it as a new request and JSESSIONID is set to null, but I don't know how to control it.

Is there any part or solution I need to check?

Enable third-party acceptance of Chrome -> Same symptoms
Attempt to control JSESSIONID on Spring filter -> Logs already set to null